# Wpf Charting with x axis as time in minutes for one day and y axis as variable inputs range is not specified?

Tags: c#, wpf, charts

I need x axis as time in minutes as 00:00, 00:01, 00:02 ,00:03 ....00:60,01:00,...59:50,...59:59,00:00 
if possible to show current date from system date time. and the x axis has to move to left for the whole day. and continue so on.

and y axis 0 to 65324 or may vary accordingly depending on the points it reads but i thik that is the max limit.

How to draw a line chart in wpf with a free source control?

I have tried to worked with WPF Toolkit but not able to find a solution
and now iam using Dynamic Data Display (D3) which is easy but i dont have this type of example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [OxyPlot](https://oxyplot.codeplex.com/). It's free, and I've used it in several of my projects.

You can start with the official page, but here's a good example that will set you on the right trail:

- [line chart + live data](http://blog.bartdemeyer.be/2013/03/creating-graphs-in-wpf-using-oxyplot/).

You'll have to modify the axis a bit, but it's not too dificult.

Here's a screenshot from the above link:

[image]